# Easy way to change value of boolean

Tags: c#

I often have inverse logic between my forms and data. I am looking for the easiest (most elegant) way to change some boolean from true to false and vice versa.
I know that a lot of people will get angry if they see code like this:

```
if (c)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

Or something like this:

EDIT:

I am sorry, my code sample is not good.
How do I find the inverse value of a boolean in a more elegant way?

```
myMethod(!op.checkBoxSamoSaKol.Checked) // Is this possibile
```

Comment: Ofcourse it is possible.

Comment: Have you even tried? Your code sample should compile just fine.

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen Yes I did but in between I edited my question already, and I didn't wont to edit again it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you'll find that is called the 'not' operator.

```
return !CheckBoxOnContolOnForm.Checked;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return, just do it like this

```
return CheckBoxOnContolOnForm.Checked;
```

If you want to invert a boolean value, the simplest is this syntax:

```
myBool = !myBool;
```

**EDIT**

In your case I see you want to return false if it's checked. In that case it should be written like this:

```
return !CheckBoxOnContolOnForm.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible expression would be (as Øyvind Bråthen) suggested as follows

```
return !CheckBoxOnContolOnForm.Checked;
```